# check if a two different string contain two different specific words in php

Tags: php

my code is:

```
$key  = strtolower( trim( $_REQUEST['key'] ) );
$cat  = strtolower( trim( $_REQUEST['categories'] ) );
$loc  = strtolower( trim( $_REQUEST['locations'] ) );
$ttle = strtolower( trim( $title ) );
$lloc = strtolower( trim( $exp[0] ) );

/*I am not getting any results with this*/
if( (strstr( $ttle, $key ) && ( strstr($lloc,$loc) ) ) {
    //echo some thing
}
```

how can I find some if a two different string contain two different specific words.

Comment: plz put proper format on your code.. its hard to read

Comment: Please, read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/

Answer (score 3):

use `strpos()`:

```
if((strpos($ttle, $key) !== false) && (strpos($lloc,$loc) !== false)) {
    //echo some thing
}
```

- [strstr() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

> Returns part of haystack string starting from and including the first
>   occurrence of needle to the end of haystack.

- [strpos() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found. Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir. I used it but no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
if( ( strstr($ttle, $key) != "" ) && ( strstr($lloc,$loc) !="" ) )  {
  //echo some thing  
}
```